# How to use read() function to read data from a file in C?

Tags: c, file

I would like to read data from a file, I need to open file in binary form and read blocks of data at a time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
  int n;
  FILE * fp;
  size_t nbyte;
  unsigned char * buffer[1024];
  fp=open("file_test.txt",O_RDONLY);
  read(fp,buffer,1);  
    printf("%s\n",buffer[0]);
    close(fp);
 
  return 0;
  
   

}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation or at your learning material? Basically your need [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [`close`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html). Also read this: [ask]

Comment: [Documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read) – with example included.

Comment: `unsigned char * buffer[1024]` -> `unsigned char buffer[1024]`. Other than that: you don't check if `open` succeeds and you're only reading a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

`open`/`read` is the POSIX version of `fopen`/`fread`, `open` does not return `FILE*` pointer.

`unsigned char * buffer[1024];` is for array of character strings. You just need a buffer `unsigned char buffer[1024];`

`printf("%s\n",...);` is for printing c-string, it cannot print binary data in general.

```
int main(void)
{
    int fin = open("file_test.txt", O_BINARY | O_RDONLY);
    if (!fin)
        return 0;
    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    while (1)
    {
        size_t size = read(fin, buffer,  sizeof(buffer));
        if (size == 0) 
            break;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("%02X ", buffer[i]);
        //break; print the whole file!
    }
    close(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants rather open/read/close instead of fopen/fread/fclose.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I changed the answer since the question is about `read()`, but based on asker's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70201847/) `fread` will probably do.